# Determining mapping cone of free resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, homological-algebra, tensor-products

I am reading the concept of [mapping cone of a resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)). I need help with the following.

Let $I_1=\langle x_1^2-x_2 x_4, x_1 x_2-x_3 x_4, x_1 x_3-x_4^2,x_2^2-x_1 x_3, x_2 x_3-x_1 x_4,x_3^2-x_2 x_4 \rangle \subseteq R_1=\mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$

and
$I_2= \langle x_5^2-x_6 x_8, x_5 x_6 -x_7 x_8, x_5 x_7-x_8^2,x_6^2-x_5 x_7,x_6 x_7-x_5 x_8,x_7^2-x_6 x_8 \rangle \subseteq R_2=\mathbb{K}[x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8]$

are two ideals
with $R_i$-minimal free resolution of $I_i$ given by $\mathbf{F}_i$, for $i=1,2$ respectively.

Let $J=I_1 +I_2+\langle x_4-x_8 \rangle \subseteq R=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_4,x_5,\dots,x_8]$ be an ideal. What will be the $R$-minimal free resolution of $J$?

I think using tensor product of free resolution $\mathbf{F}_1 \otimes \mathbf{F}_2$  and then from mapping cone we can obtained minimal free resolution of $J$. But, I don't able to prove this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect kind of question for a computer algebra package such as Macaulay2. https://macaulay2.com/ I highly recommend learning how to use this if you need to computations like this.

The main issue here is the emphasis on "minimal". What you propose sounds fine for producing a free resolution. But it may be subtle to prove that it is in fact minimal.

Comment: I already checked this with Macaulay-2, and there I got the minimal free resolution. But theoretically, I am still figuring out the proof.  If some how we can prove that $f=x_4-x_8$ is a non-zero divisor in $\frac{R}{I_1+I_2}$, then we can prove the required result.

Comment: @Raman This is always context-dependent but I had a closer look. The zero set of each of your ideals is a union of 4 lines and is a Cohen-Macaulay scheme (since pdim = codim = 3). So when you tensor together, you get a union of 16 5-planes. The equation $x_4-x_8$ is linearly independent on each of these 5-planes, so will cut its dimension down, so it's a NZD by C-M property (probably there is an easier way to argue, but I'll just use what's there).

Comment: Whoops, I meant 2-planes, not 5-planes.